# Unpack function parameter types in the definition of another template function

Tags: c++, visual-studio, template-meta-programming

I'm making a class template to encode function pointers. The function can have any result type and number / type of parameters. This is what I have:

```
LPVOID EncodePtr(LPVOID ptr) {
  // Encode...
  return ptr;
}

LPVOID DecodePtr(LPVOID ptr) {
  // Decode...
  return ptr;
}

template<class T>
class encoded_ptr {
public:

  typedef encoded_ptr<T> _Myt;

  encoded_ptr() {
    ptr_ = (T*)EncodePtr(nullptr);
  }

  // Irresponsible?
  template<class _OtherType>
  encoded_ptr(_OtherType ptr) {
    ptr_ = (T*)DecodePtr((LPVOID)ptr);
  }

  ~encoded_ptr() {
    ptr_ = (T*)EncodePtr(nullptr);
  }

  // Makes it possible to call the function directly
  template<class... _Args>
  typename std::result_of<T*(_Args...)>::type operator()(_Args... _Ax) {
    T* fn = get();

    return fn(_Ax...);
  }

  T* get() const {
    return (T*)DecodePtr((LPVOID)ptr_);
  }

  bool is_set() {
    return (get() != nullptr);
  }

private:
  T* ptr_;
};
```

It works as expected. Eg.:

```
encoded_ptr<decltype(MessageBoxA)> MsgBox;
MsgBox = &MessageBoxA; // Could also initialize in the constructor

// (HWND)0 is justified by the actual problem in the question
MsgBox((HWND)0, "Test message!", "Test", 0);
```

The first problem is that the way the parenthesis operator `()` is declared doesn't allow Visual Studio's IntelliSense to make its magic and give me hints about the function parameters:

```
template<class... _Args>
typename std::result_of<T*(_Args...)>::type operator()(_Args... _Ax) {
  T* fn = get();

  return fn(_Ax...);
}
```

Instead of using `(_Args... _Ax)`, I'd like to unpack the actual function parameters so that IntelliSense can give hints correctly.

**Current behaviour is:**

[image: Wrong]

**Expected behaviour is:**

[image]

The second problem is that calling the function this way, the compiler doesn't do basic casts, forcing me to cast `NULL` to `(void*)NULL`, `0` to `(HWND)0`, etc. This is annoying when using functions with a lot of parameters.

Maybe there are some mistakes in the implementation but I'm not a template expert. Also, I don't know if the title of the question fits properly.

I appreciate any help.

**EDIT:**

What I've tried so far (@OlegBogdanov's suggestion):

```
template<class T, class... Args>
class encoded_ptr;

template<class T, class... Args>
class encoded_ptr<T(Args...)> {
public:

  typedef encoded_ptr<T> _Myt;

  using Fptr = T(*)(Args...);
  encoded_ptr(Fptr ptr) {
    ptr_ = (Fptr)EncodePtr((LPVOID)ptr);
  }

  // Makes it possible to call the function directly
  typename T operator()(Args... _Ax) {
    Fptr fn = get();

    return fn(std::forward<Args>(_Ax)...);
  }

  Fptr get() const {
    return (T*)DecodePtr((LPVOID)ptr_);
  }

  bool is_set() {
    return (get() != nullptr);
  }

private:
  Fptr ptr_;
};
```

Result: Cannot instantiate / use the constructor: `Incomplete type is not allowed`.

**EDIT:**

That was the right direction, the problem was the calling convention.

Changed:

`class encoded_ptr<T(Args...)>` to `class encoded_ptr<T(__stdcall)(Args...)>`, and

`using Fptr = T(*)(Args...)` to `using Fptr = T(__stdcall*)(Args...)`

I'm trying to detect the calling convention instead of having it hardcoded.

Comment: so you are effectively fighting IntelliSense not the the code issues?

Comment: I'm not fighting IntelliSense. It's the opposite. I'd be glad to accept suggestions.

Comment: But still, you dont have any compilation issues or runtime issues, you just are not happy with what IntelliSense tells you? this is different kind of story

Comment: Please see the second problem in the updated answer, about being forced to do very basic casts.

Comment: if you need to accommodate for calling conventions and maybe different call targrets i.e. not only free functions but objects, lambdas.. you will really have to copy most/all of std::function implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your expectations of

```
template<class... _Args>
typename std::result_of<T*(_Args...)>::type operator()(_Args... _Ax) {
  T* fn = get();

  return fn(_Ax...);
}
```

are wrong. It completely ignore's your target functions argument list (you have used poor mans type erasure) and passes (I wanted to use word 'forwards' but that would be inaccurate) whatever caller gives in. Thus 0 in

```
MsgBox(0, "Test message!", "Test", 0);
```

is deduced as `int` and you have to cast it to `HWND`, there's no way compiler would guess it otherwise.

What you are really doing is re-inventing the [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) or sort of wrapper above it.

If you really think that [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) is not enough for your needs you will have to copy parts of its implementation, namely you would need to have at least

```
    template<class R, class... Args>
    class encoded_ptr; // leaving this undefined

    template<class R, class... Args>
    class encoded_ptr<R(Args...)> {

    using Fptr = R(*)(Args...);
    encoded_ptr(Fptr ptr) {
        ptr_ = (T*)DecodePtr((LPVOID)ptr);
    }
    ...
```

to capture argument list in your type

and call operator would re-use it instead of randomly typed passed arguments:

```
// this must not be here -> template<class... _Args>
R operator()(Args... _Ax) {
  T* fn = get()

  return fn(std::forward<Args>(_Ax)...);
}
```

---

Edit:

You can't store but `T*` anymore, `T` is just a return type, store by `Fptr`

Comment: The purpose of the class is not to just store the function for calling it later. It's an encoded wrapper/pointer to store it safely in other classes that may need it. Why do I need this safety? You could also ask "Why does Microsoft provide `EncodePointer()` and `DecodePointer()`" ?

Comment: `Encode/DecodePointer` APIs are means of obfuscation, they have not much to do with safety, unless we have a different view on what safety is :) But It's perfectly fine if you need to build on top of `std::function`, it should give you the idea of how to achieve what you want

Comment: The goal is to make a cracker's life a bit difficult. Just an extra layer, not a perfect solution for it. Maybe the correct word isn't "safe". And yes, I appreciate your help because I still have no idea on how to do it.

Comment: I've slightly edited the answer adding the constructor to new encoded_ptr, what would stop you now from finishing it?

Comment: Ok, I'm trying: `encoded_ptr<decltype(MessageBoxA)> MsgBox((decltype(MessageBoxA)*)&MessageBoxA)`, but the constructor doesn't accept the argument.

Comment: I've update my answer with slight correction: template must be specialized for function type

Comment: the way you should use it simpler: `encoded_ptr<decltype(MessageBoxA)> MsgBox(&MessageBoxA)`

Comment: I'm trying exactly like that. `Incomplete type is not allowed.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130388/discussion-between-oleg-bogdanov-and-karliwson).